# Why does CMD output the error message ")))) was unexpected at this time" on batch file execution?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, syntax-error

This is my first question so I don't know the most format and rules :)

This is the code:

```
:verifi
cls
if %money% leq 99999 (
    set /a verimoney=%verimoneys% - %money%
    echo.
    echo You have not enough money.
    echo You need %moneyveri% money to verify your channel.
    pause
    goto topyt
)
if %verified% == 1 (
    echo.
    echo.
    echo Your channel is verified channel.
    pause >nul
    goto topyt
)
if %subscriber% leq 99999 (
    set /a subsneed=%verisub% - %subscriber%
    echo.
    echo.
    echo You don't have enough subscribers.
    echo You need %subsneed% to become verified.
    pause >nul
    goto topyt
)
if %verified% == 0 (
    set /a %money% - 100000
    set verified=1
    echo Verified successfully!
    pause
    goto topyt
) else (
    set /a %money% - 100000
    echo Verify failed!
    pause
    goto topyt
```

There is output on execution of the batch file:

> )))) was unexpected at this time.

I changed my code so many times and the output was always the same. I am a beginner in batch script writing.

Comment: looks like you are missing a closing bracket at the end of your code after the else statement, could this be the issue?

Comment: Without going into the many errors present and the fact the code shared is not the entirety of the offending code, `xyz unexpected at this time` is a syntax error where the interpreter encounters something (`xyx`) where it does not syntactically belong.

Comment: You have failed to provide a [mcve].